# Move all existing changes under a folder to desired changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

If changes for a folder already exist in the default changelist (or other changelists), I want to collect them all in one changelist. How can I accomplish this in perforce, preferably P4V?

Comment: You cant do this with P4V.  Sam Stafford's answer can be done via command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line:

```
p4 reopen -c CHANGE //depot/folder/...
```

In P4V, select the files and do Actions > Move Files to Another Changelist.

Comment: Don't know about the p4 command but I want to avoid selecting the files one by one in p4v myself. I want to select automatically all files that are checked out, then move them to my changelist.

Comment: Open the default changelist, select a file, Ctrl+A to Select All, then drag them into the other changelist.

Comment: It's not guaranteed the default changelist will have all the changes. They might be scattered around different changelists. But your command line answer works Thanks :)

Comment: If this is something you do often, it'd be pretty easy to add a "Custom Tool" to P4V that will show up as a context menu when you right-click a pending changelist and run that "p4 reopen" command with that specified changelist and a filespec of "//..." so it pulls all open files into that changelist.

Comment: did not know there was that option. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

Perforce doesn't understand relative directories, so you **have** to type the full path name, which I hated doing each time. So I added the command from @sam-stafford's answer as a custom tool to P4V.

To add the command to the Perforce GUI: [image: P4V custom tool]

To use, you can right click the depot folder and choose "Move all changes under folder to changelist.."

Note: The changelist should be an existing one. I don't know how you would create a new one from the custom tools.

Comment: FWIW Perforce does recognize relative directories as long as you're in a workspace.  :)